# Spring Rest and Hibernate and JSON dosnt work as expected

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am developing rest web app with spring framework, Hibernate and JSON.
Assume that I have two entities like below:

University.java

```
 public class University extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String telephon;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy = "university")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();
// setter an getter
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student extends BaseEntity{

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String section;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIVERSITY_ID",nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private University university;

// setter an getter
    }
```

My requirement:

When I call student list api, I need to have Usiversity object in each student object,
What kind of config or annotation I need to handle this situation?
the result is:

```
   [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "aa",
        "lastName": "aa",
        "section": "aa"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "bb",
        "lastName": "bb",
        "section": "bb"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "cc",
        "lastName": "cc",
        "section": "cc"
    }
]
```

and I need to have this responses
when I call student list

```
   [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "aa",
        "lastName": "aa",
        "section": "aa",
        "university": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "string",
            "address": "string",
            "telephon": "string"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "bb",
        "lastName": "bb",
        "section": "bb",
        "university": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "string",
            "address": "string",
            "telephon": "string"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "cc",
        "lastName": "cc",
        "section": "cc",
        "university": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "www",
            "address": "www",
            "telephon": "www"
        }
    }
]
```

**update:**

and for university list I need this response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "string",
        "address": "string",
        "telephon": "string",
        "students": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "aa",
                "lastName": "aa",
                "section": "aa"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "bb",
                "lastName": "bb",
                "section": "bb"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "www",
        "address": "www",
        "telephon": "www",
        "students": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "firstName": "cc",
                "lastName": "cc",
                "section": "cc"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help and advise appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the Jackson annotation declared the wrong way:

@JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.

@JsonBackReference is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Comment: I need to have @JsonManagedReference in University side . because if I remove it I cannot get the university list eagerly.

Comment: Why? One is JPA the other is JSON serialization.

Comment: jpa doing it perfectly, But when I need both side eagerly it get in trouble with json. Which side that have @JsonManagedReference it will work.

Comment: What do you mean by get in trouble? The one side is eager by default.

Comment: I need to have @JsonManagedReference in university side because in my beasuness i need to 1. load universisty eagerly 2. adding student side object in university in inserting university

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem. Just change the Jackson annotations the right way and then everything works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156364/discussion-between-generic-and-simas-ch).